# Unable to connect external monitor to Ubuntu 22.04 using NVIDIA GeForce MX550

Tags: nvidia, monitor

I have tried every option in the Additional Drivers and anything I could find on the internet but still unable to connect my monitor. Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,